# I want a measure to avoid being filtered by a bar chat axis

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a bar chart with a variable "MBA Type" in the axis.

"MBA Type" is a categorical variable with the following possible successive values: {MBA-LB, MBA1, MBA2, EMAP}

Values are calculated from the measure "Student variation", which should count the difference between the number of students in each MBA type and the number of students when "MBA Type" == LB.

Student variation should follow this logic: A - B, where A should be responsive to the Axis values, and B should have always "MBA Type"= MBA-LB

For illustration, you can find the following chart (what I currently have):

[image: two muppets]

I would like the value corresponding to MBA-LB (17) to be subtracted from each bar. (i.e. MBA-LB=0, MBA1=-10, MBA2=-16, EMAP=-13)

Additionally, I would like to apply other filters to this visual. So I cannot use the following for calculating B:

```
B = 
VAR
    VAR_MBALB = FILTER(ALL('Table'), 'Table'[MBA Type] = "MBA-LB")
RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[students]), VAR_MBALB)
```

I guess a solution might be to prevent B from being affected by the variable "MBA Type", and fix a specific value to it.
Any ideas on how I can do this?

Any comment or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: How about FILTER(ALL('Table'[MBA Type]). . .?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much David!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [All function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax)

> ALL(Table)    Removes all filters from the specified table.
>
> ALL (Column[, Column[, …]])   Removes all filters from the specified
>   columns in the table; all other filters on other columns in the table
>   still apply.

So if you want to remove only the filter on MBA Type then use:

```
B = 
VAR
    VAR_MBALB = FILTER(ALL('Table'[MBA Type]), 'Table'[MBA Type] = "MBA-LB")
RETURN
    CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[students]), VAR_MBALB)
```